# Increase Javascript Mouse Events

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I would like to know if is there any way to increase the sample rate of mousemove events of JS.
When I  cross the window quickly I only get around 10-20 events, not enough for the purpose
of the app, when I do it slowly I can reach +100;

Thanks in advance,

Comment: unable to understand your question!!

Comment: you mean onmousemove?  The ratio of its firing?

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about the `mousemove` event. If that's true, then it fires every time the mouse moves by a single pixel.

Comment: Yes,I mean onmousemove. I Think thats not true, as I said, If I cross the whole window very quickly I only get 10-20 events for 800 pixels.

Comment: Try this and you can see that the event fires for every pixel, as the value in the text field changes (move cursor around "Result" frame): http://jsfiddle.net/t6Thj/

Comment: try it: http://jsfiddle.net/t6Thj/8/

Comment: It depends on the speed of the mouse movement. In conclusion, on the sample rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, but maybe i'm wrong, that `mousemove` events "sample rate" is not determined by javascript, but from the sample rate of your mouse. This means that whenever the mouse sends an event to the browser, an event is fired (if the mouse has moved of at least one pixel) and you can respond to it. 
Mouse with higher sample rates create more events (and are more precise), where mouse with lower sample rate create fewer events. This is why when you play quake 4 the sample rate of your mouse affects the precision of your aiming.

So i don't think it's a problem of javascript, and you should have your app respond accordingly to the events generated from the mouse. The same thing is done in first person shooter with the auto aiming option.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Ill try to increase the sample rate of the mouse properties to get more mouse events.